# Fuzzy matching two columns in R or Python

Tags: python, r

We all know how to match a string in a vector using fuzzy method like to find a string "adam" in a vector like A <- c("Madam", "adam", "Lizzy", "Paul").

We can do a `grep, grep("adam", A)` and we get the index of the elements matching

How to match two vectors like this using fuzzy method?

For example, I have two vectors `A <- c("007996", "12390", "09123")` and `B <- c("7996", "9823", "9123")`. I have to perform a fuzzy match between A and B so that I get the index of matching elements in A, in this case 1 3

as 7996 is present in 00796 and 9123 is present in 09123

I tried performing `grep(B, A)`, but R is throwing an error stating that it will consider only the first element in B, as the matching pattern is more than one on length

Can anyone please suggest a way to do this in R without using a FOR Loop.

The two vectors may not be of same size.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You talk about fata.frames but your examples are only vectors, can you edit to reflect you real situation better ?

Comment: `sapply(B, function(x) grep(pattern = x, A))`

Comment: If I use sapply() as suggested above, I get the following warning message and no results are returned

`In grep(pattern = x, Policy) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: Then you either have different declarations of `A` and `B` or a typo.

Comment: `grep(paste0(B, collapse = "|"), A)` ?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer they are different

Comment: @RonakShah thank you... its working for certain cases but is not completely correct

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a matter of leading `"0"` you can do:

```
A <- c("007996", "12390", "09123")
B <- c("7996", "9823", "9123")

which(as.numeric(A) %in% as.numeric(B)) 
# [1] 1 3

# or here just which(as.numeric(A) %in% B)
```

Or maybe :

```
which(as.numeric(A) == as.numeric(B))
# [1] 1 3
```

It's not clear to me if you're looking for pairwise matches or not.